# Javascript Closure calling a Call back function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I have tons of function that are very similar to each other. IE time to refactor via closures but I ran into a problem.

My functions skeleton code is something like this (i have tons of this in my javascript):

```
function getBlahOutputInThisID(param1, ...., paramN, functionName) {
    var jasonArray = {
        param1: param1,
        param2: param2,
        ...
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/blahController/ajax_functionName/',
        data: jasonArray,
        success: function(data) {
          //Some REALLY custom function stuff
        }
    });
}
```

So since I have tons of these:

I was wondering if I can do a closure

```
function closure(paramArray, customFUNCTION) {
    return function() {
        //getBlahOutputInThisID code (the skeleton code, look above)
    }
}
```

and have it call the callback function, customFunction in the closure (the `jQuery.ajax({` part), ie:

```
 success: function(data) {
          customFunction()
        }
```

Or is this a very noob/bad way to refactor codes?

Edit: Thank you for your time and effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend this

- This will reduce the size of your code leading to faster page load
- It is easier to maintain this code coz if some bug is found, you just need to fix it in one place
- etc etc etc

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure about needing two levels here.  This is how I see it working:

```
function getBlahOutputInThisID(param1, ...., paramN, functionName, ajaxCallback) {
    var jasonArray = {
        param1: param1,
        param2: param2,
        ...
    }
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/blahController/ajax_functionName/',
        data: jasonArray,
        success: ajaxCallback
        }
    });
```

this you could use it every time like this:

```
   var a;

   getBlahOutputInThisID(param1, ...., paramN, functionName,function (data) {
      // here is all my custom stuff
      // reference var a above as a closure.
   });
```

Comment: +1 You are right. You don't really need to introduce another level (i.e. the `closure` function).  Note: you have an extra `}` on the line after `success: ajaxCallback`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a good idea. Definitely easier to understand the overall code, once you know what the `closure` funcntion does. I wouldn't call it "noob" either, because a solid understanding of closures is not really noob. The only thing I would do differently is that I would not name the function `closure`, since that doesn't tell you anything about what it does. The name should indicate that it is doing an AJAX call.

Comment: I don't think these are doing the AJAX call -- they are handling the return from an AJAX call.  A clear indication that closure is a bad name as you suggest.

Comment: @Hogan - Good point, since the function `closure` does not actually do the AJAX call. Rather, the function it returns does the AJAX call, and then jQuery invokes the callback function.